# Edit css of javadoc

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc

I am generating javadoc via gradle with this script:

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    failOnError false
    options.overview = "src/main/javadoc/overview.html"
}
```

I would like to add css to the generated overview-summary.html. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS-stylesheet in the following way...

```
options.stylesheetFile = new File(projectDir, "src/main/javadoc/style.css");
```

Comment: Can you update your answer? This is working syntax: options.stylesheetFile = new File(projectDir, "src/main/javadoc/style.css")